# The relation between least-square estimation in two seemingly related problems

Tags: estimation, least-squares

I am presenting here a very simplified problem, because I have a feeling that if I'll understand this I will be on my way to understand my original problem. I tried googeling this and also searched this site but couldn't find the answer I needed. Hopefully you'll be able to point me to the right direction.

I am solving two seemingly related problems using least square minimization given a set of random measurments $\{x_i\}$.

The first problem is finding $b$ to minimize 
$$\sum_i^n (x_i - b)^2 $$

The second problem is finding $c$ to minimize
$$ \sum_i^n (\frac{x_i}{c} - 1)^2 $$

The solution is obviously the average of $x_i$ for $b$ 
$$ b = \frac{\sum_i^n x_i}{n} $$
while for $c$ it is
$$ c = \frac{\sum_i^n x_i^2}{\sum_i^n x_i} $$

Naively I would expect $c$ to be the average as well. My logic: I expect $c$ to answer the question "which number, when dividing each number in the set, make the average of the resulting set closest to $1$". Obviously I'm wrong and that's not the way least-square works. Why is $c$ not the average? What does $c$ mean?

Comment: Well, $\sum_i^n (x_i - b)^2 = b^2\sum_i(x_i/b - 1)^2 \neq \sum_i(x_i/b - 1)^2$, so in each of these problems, you're minimizing totally different losses. I don't see a relation to these two problems. Can I ask why you're trying to find $c$?

Comment: Basically you are beeing mislead by your intuition which seemingly ignores the ^2

Answer (score 3):

In the case of **b**, the question being asked is "What scalar is closest to my data points (in the least squares sense)?" In the case of **c**, the question being asked is "How can I scale my data points to make each as close as possible to 1 (in the least squares sese)?" These objective functions are different. Imagine the case if your data had mean of 1 with extremely high variance. The optimal value of **b** would be 1 (up to noise), but **c** would not be 1 - it would necessarily be large to counter the data's high variance.